# Como valido esta consulta en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->select('id_Program')
         ->where("name","=",$row['name'])
         ->first('id_Program')->id_Program
```

Erro:
Trying to get property 'id_Program' of non-object

Comment: quitale ese ->id_Program del final y hazle un dd($id_program) para ver que te retorna

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que con escribirlo así simplemente funcionaría: **`$id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->select('id_Program')
         ->where('name',$row['name'])
         ->first()`**

Comment: Si le quito el ->  ->id_Program  me devuelve "id_Program" : 4 y si lo agrego solo me da el 4 que es lo que necesito

Answer (score 1):

Si, como parece ser, quieres obtener el valor de una columna solamente (`id_Program`).

La documentación dice lo siguiente en el apartado titulado: [***Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results):

> Si ni siquiera necesita una fila completa, puede extraer un único
>   valor de un registro utilizando el método `value`. Este método
>   devolverá el valor de la columna directamente:
>
> ```
> $email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');
> ```

Entonces, para obtener el valor de la columna `id_Program`, puedes hacer esto simplemente:

```
$id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->
         ->where('name',$row['name'])
         ->value('id_Program');
```

Comment: también se puede si el modelo se llama Program hacer lo siguiente `$id_program = Program::select('id_program')
  ->where('name', $row['name'])
  ->first();`

Comment: Asi me trae todo el registro y solo quiero el Id del registro, ¿No se si me explico?

Comment: @Israelgtz ¿así no te trae solamente el valor de `id_Program`?: **`$id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->
         ->where('name',$row['name'])
         ->value('id_Program');`** Es la forma que indica la doc cuando se quiere una sola columna. Debería funcionar.

Comment: @A.Cedano $id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->
         ->where('name',$row['name'])
         ->value('id_Program');  esto me funciono correctamente

Comment: @Israelgtz debe funcionar, es la forma que indica la doc. He edita la respuesta, documentándola. Si resolvió tu problema la puedes aceptar y votar a favor. Me alegro de que te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_program_= DB::table('Programs')->select('id_Program')<br/>
         ->where("name","=",$row['name'])<br/>
         ->first();
```

Para obtener el resultado seria `$id_program->id_Program;`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto.

```
$sql= DB::table('Programs')
->select('id_Program')
->where("name","=",$row['name'])
->get(); 

$id_Program = $sql->first()['id_Program'];
```